# Ampliar uma imagem ao clicar nela (HTML5 e CSS3)?

Tags: html5, css3

Estou com um problema, em smartphone o hover do css3 não é reconhecido (ou melhor, demora uns 5 segundos para ser reconhecido), e eu queria fazer uma interatividade com as fotos do meu app, como não posso usa o hover estou perdido, não sei o que fazer, mas a solução seria ampliar a imagem (ou fazer outros efeitos) quando o usuário clica/pressionar (n)ela.. Porém não sei fazer isso, tentei um pouco usando Jquery mas não consegui, não vou postar código pois não tenho.. Posso colocar a foto de qualquer jeito, seja como imagem ou background.

Comment: Olá, qual código que você está utilizando?

Comment: para isso nenhum, só montei uma pagina modelo com o html, estilo css e dois javascript, um para o menu e outro para um botão de voltar ao topo, alem do jquery completão..  Daí com tudo pronto fui colocar a imagem e tentar fazer esse efeito, estava entando usar o `-webkit-transition: all .4s ease-in;` e o `-webkit-transform: scale(1.5);` para transição e escala, respectivamente, funcionou só com o hover (com um bug), mas para smartphone preciso de usar quando clicar, daí que veio a confusão, tentei fazer igual fiz com o menu mas não deu..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amigo procure por essa propriedade do css [focus](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_focus.asp) e tamém por [keyframes](http://tableless.com.br/css3-animation-keyframe/) esses dois links estão bem explicados você poderá juntar um com o outro e ter o efeito que você quer  pois a propriedade `:focus` e ativada com o click e você poera assim misturar a ação de click o `:focus` com o `keyframe`

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer usando o animate do jQuery, como no exemplo que criei

### [EXEMPLO AQUI](http://jsfiddle.net/96qee9z2/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Existem ferramentas prontas para tal como o [Lightbox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/#examples) ou [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/). Ou mesmo você pode baixar o código fonte de uma dessas soluções, estudar e desenvolver a sua própria solução.
Você pode também usar um thumbnail com link para a imagem em tamanho grande (de modo mais simples).